# Mysterious Brown bumps; bugs, bug eggs, or maybe disease?

Tags: identification, pests, nut-trees

[image: Brown bumps on my potted hazelnut tree]

As it is springtime, I'm looking over my many plants (I'm located in Seattle) and I saw these brown bumps, they are one one of my for Little hazelnut trees. At least that's all I have found so far.

Are these something you recognize? I have not seen them before and I have spend a good couple hours searching for references but nothing is clicking so far. They are about ladybug size, not moving, and I'm very curious what they might be!

Answer (score 3):

It's scale insect, most likely brown scale. These are the adults and the crawlers or nymphs will likely shortly be present. You can rub off the scale insects wearing gloves, or use a disposable cloth to scrape them off, but you may need to spray with insecticide as well, when you see the crawlers or immature scales. Information on scale insect and treatments for it here https://pnwhandbooks.org/insect/nut/hazelnut/hazelnut-scale-insect